# Runtime error SIGSEGV on SPOJ

Tags: runtime-error, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve problem ARDA1 - The hunt for Gollum on SPOJ 
Here's the link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ARDA1/ 
And here's my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string map[2010];
string marshes[310];
char str[310];

int main()
{
    int N1, N2, M1, M2 = 0;

    freopen("INPUT.txt","rt",stdin);
    scanf("%d%d", &N1, &N2);
    for (int i = 0; i < N1; i++) {
        scanf("%s", &str);
        marshes[i] = str;
    }

    scanf("%d%d", &M1, &M2);
    for (int i = 0; i < M1; i++) {
        scanf("%s", &str);
        map[i] = str;
    }

    bool isFound = false;

    for (int i = 0; i <= M1 - N1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= M2 - N2; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == marshes[0][0]) {
                bool isSame = true;
                for (int t = 0; t < N1; t++) {
                    if (marshes[t] != map[i+t].substr(j, N2)) {
                        isSame = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isSame) {
                    printf("(%d,%d)\n", i+1, j+1);
                    isFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
    if (!isFound)
        printf("NO MATCH FOUND...");
    return 0;
}
```

But I got "Runtime error (SIGSEGV)" when I submit my solution. I know that we get SIGSEGV when trying to access elements out of bound or when there's not enough memory.
I checked my code but couldn't find anything wrong and it worked on my computer. Anyone can tell me what could be wrong here?